# Default store is inactive

Tags: database, log, magento2.4.5

I start to see this error message below saying the **Default store is inactive**, but my stores are working fine, how could I solve it?

```
[2023-02-21T19:23:08.544484+00:00] report.ERROR: Default store is inactive [] []
[2023-02-21T19:23:08.548645+00:00] report.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: Default store is inactive in /app/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php:183
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(126): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getDefaultStoreById('3')
#1 /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId()
#2 /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\Interceptor->___callParent('getCurrentStore...', Array)      
#3 /app/vendor/magento/module-staging/Plugin/Store/Model/StoreResolver.php(77): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
```

[image: Default store is inactive]

Answer (score 0):

In you error log we can see this code snippet bellow:

```
getDefaultStoreById('3')
```

So check if your store with the ID 3 is active by running this SQL command below.

```
select * from store;
```

Then you can activate it, by running:

```
update store set is_active=1 where store_id=3;
```